# How to do alternate column sorting on two columns?

Tags: sorting, neo4j, cypher, alternating

I know how to sort by two columns. But I wanted to know how to sort by alternate columns in neo4j.

Node name = Product

```
   value  |  version 
    1     |   2      
    4     |   1      
    2     |   1      
    4     |   1      
    2     |   1      
    3     |   2
```

There are 2 values of versions 1 and 2. And value can be anything. First it will give higher value of version 1 , then it will give higher value of version 2, then it will give second higher value of version 1 , then it will give second higher value of version 2, and so on.

```
   value  |  version 
    4     |   1      
    3     |   2      
    4     |   1      
    1     |   2      
    2     |   1      
    1     |   1
```

I don't know this type of sorting logically done or not through cypher query. I havn't done this type of logic in mysql also. Anyone can give me such clue of ne4j cypher query.

**Update :**

```
Match (p:Product) 
RETURN p.value as value, p.version as version
ORDER BY version ASC, value DESC
```

This query sorts by version first then sorts by value. I don't want it.
I want alternate sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
unwind[1,2,3] AS value unwind[1,2] AS version

RETURN value, version
ORDER BY value DESC , version ASC

value   version
3   1
3   2
2   1
2   2
1   1
1   2
```

Comment: See updated question. I need version 1's highest then version 2's highest, and so on.

Comment: Did you see my question? Is it possible at all or not in neo4j query?